# Google Colab: How can I hide these execution line outputs?

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I'm training a GAN on google colab and every few epochs, I'll output the model losses. However, this 4/4 time line is output after every batch iteration. How can I stop this from outputting?

[image]